# Java Cucumber does not recognize my string parameter

Tags: java, junit, cucumber, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

Cucumber doesn't recognize the String parameter what I would like to use it as currency. It only recognise int value. (It finds the steps because other steps works)

```
@When("I deposit {int} of {string}")
public void testDeposit(int value, String currency) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
```

It shows the following error message:

```
There were undefined steps. You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:

@When("I deposit {int} of GBP")
public void i_deposit_of_GBP(Integer int1) {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new cucumber.api.PendingException();
}

@Then("My balance is {int} of GBP")
public void my_balance_is_of_GBP(Integer int1) {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new cucumber.api.PendingException();
}
```

- Given I created an account
- When I deposit 100 of GBP
- Then My balance is 100 of GBP

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/cucumber-expressions/

> {string} Matches single-quoted or double-quoted strings,
> for example "banana split" or 'banana split' (but not banana split).

For your currency code that does not have any quotes (nor any spaces), you want `{word}`, so:

```
 @When("I deposit {int} of {word}")
```